# Strapi V3.0.1 - Where are my plugins setting buttons?

Tags: strapi

after I have updated my strapi, can I no longer find the plugin setting buttons? What went wrong?

Please see screenshot?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

@Derrick Mehaffy: Thank you for the quick reply for the first time! By the way, I use Sendgrid. Unfortunately I can't solve the problem yet and got the following error message. Where is Unauthorized? Everything looks okay.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following notice on the Strapi Github: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6710

> As of beta.20.x as well as all stable releases 3.x.x provider settings
>   for both email and upload have been moved to file based meaning you
>   will now configure them via the ./config/plugins.js file and not via
>   the admin.

Media Library is now in the settings menu on the left

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, unfortunately I have not managed it yet. I added two new screenshots above, can you give me a tip?

Comment: Thanks again for the tips, I did it! However, "env" in "env ('SENDGRID_API_KEY')" had to be removed. Have a nice day! :)